# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion | Spring Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have configured "**hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar**" in pom.xml as below.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>G:/Setups/hibernate-release-4.3.6.Final/hibernate-release-4.3.6.Final/lib/required/hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

When i try to inject hibernate DAO class in service layer i am getting this exception.

Comment: And the full stack trace of the exception is? Have you added all the other jar files listed under G:/Setups/hibernate-release-4.3.6.Final/hibernate-release-4.3.6.Final/lib/required? Because, as the folder name indicates, they are required. Also, do you understand what the system scope is? Read http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the scope and systemPath part and build the project again. The dependencies will be taken care by maven.

Comment: It worked. I removed scope and systemPath and saved jar file in repo directory. Thanks.

Comment: can you choose it as right answer so people can benefit from it